# In-App purchases, final steps for consumable

Tags: ios, objective-c, storekit

I'm trying to implement in-app purchases for the first time. I'm using the helper class `"ABStoreKitHelper"`. The source code can be found here: https://github.com/ablfx/ABStoreKitHelper.

I have implemented this code into my project and it runs fine. I have made a consumable in-app purchase named "coins1" (Bundle ID) that is "ready to submit" in Itunes Connect. My app has a non-wildcard Bundle ID "com.apportable.PeevedPenguins", so I feel like I have done everything necessary in preparation for consumable in-app purchases.

When a button is pressed on the main menu, I call a selector to run the method within `ABStoreKitHelper.m` named `-(void) buyProduct:(NSString*)productIdentifier;`. It runs without error, but nothing happens. I basically just want to directly go to the option to purchase the consumable when the button is pressed on my main menu. I'm not sure if there is further configuration or not that I need to do in order for this button to lead directly to the purchase. If someone could help me with this final step of in-app purchases, I would be very grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a very old library :

> ABStoreKitHelper.m

It has been over 2 years since this repo was updated, I think you need to use another up-to-date library.
In our last project, we used this tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

I hope this will help you.